# Remove from Mongoose Array based on filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in nodejs & trying to remove data from a mongoose array based on a filter like so:

```
var data = await stats.findOne({ _ID: <THEIR ID> })    
 // keep is defined elsewhere
var todaysShifts = data.shiftsWorked.filter(u => u.Date >= keep)
var workToRemove = data.shiftsWorked.filter(u => !todaysShifts.includes(u))
await stats.findOneAndUpdate({ userID: member.id }, { $pull: { shiftsWorked: workToRemove } }, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true, multi: true })
```

However despite workToRemove containing an object with values, nothing is removed. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details on data object.

Comment: How do you mean, my schema is like:
shiftsWorked: []

Comment: Yes, because if understood what's in shiftsWorked then only will be able to make conclusion.

Comment: It's a series of objects like 1 { amount: 13, Date: 38282919182 }